# Can I develop MacOS desktop applications via Visual Studio for Windows and Xamarin using a build server in the same way I would for a iOS app?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I know that using Visual Studio for Windows and Xamarin I can develop iOS applications on a Windows machine, as long as I have a Mac set up as a build server. I would like to know if I would be able to do the same in order to develop MacOS desktop applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's **impossible** to develop MacOS desktop applicaations with a Windows system machine .

Have a look at the **Requirements** from [The Official Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/get-started/hello-mac#requirements) :

Xamarin.Mac application development requires:

- A Mac computer running macOS High Sierra (10.13) or higher.
- Xcode 10 or higher.
- The latest version of Xamarin.Mac and Visual Studio for Mac.

To run an application built with Xamarin.Mac, you will need:

- A Mac computer running macOS 10.7 or greater.